# neo4j - Querying 1-N relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hello graph database lovers !

I'm a beginner with `neo4j` and I need some advice.
I'm currently trying to build a symptoms-disease model in a graph.
A disease can have multiple symptoms and a group of symptoms can only have one disease.

For now, I have this relation:

```
(d:Disease)-[h:HAS_SYMPTOM]->(s:Symptom).
```

I want to know if giving a list of symptoms we can retrieve the corresponding disease.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can a symptom be associated with more than one disease? or Does each disease have unique set of symptoms?

Comment: A symptom can be associated with more than one disease, yes !

Comment: Have you tried `MATCH (s:Symptom) -[:HAS_SYMPTOM] -(d:Disease)
RETURN d;` ?